# How to check value with all previous row value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write a formula in excel to check if the given number is less than any of the previous row value.
For eg.
My excel document is as follows:

```
        A            B
1   01/05/2017       10
2   02/05/2017       5
3   03/05/2017       7
4   04/05/2017       11
```

what m hoping to achieve is

```
        A            B      C
1   01/05/2017       10     -
2   02/05/2017       5     TRUE (5<10 = true)
3   03/05/2017       7     TRUE (7<5=false & 7<10=true therefor its true)
4   04/05/2017       11    FALSE (11<7=false & 11<5=false and 11<10=false)
```

So if the current value is less than any of the previous value the field should be true or else false.
Note : the sheet is sorted according to timestamp which cannot change

Thanks for you answers.

Comment: And what have you come up with?

Comment: I haven't . I don't have any experience with excel formulas.

Comment: I see. Look at the `MAX` function, and also how addresses change as formulas are dragged. This is not a free code-writing service but exists to help others with code or functions they are trying to develop. Please familiarize with how this site works by taking the [Two Minute Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP pages for information about [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the help. @RonRosenfeld

Comment: I think @pnuts suggestion should give correct results as desired  by you. What is the hesitation in acknowledging his suggestion.

Comment: just check if the value is smaller the max of previous ones

Comment: @pnuts it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you start in `C2` then this formula does what you want:

```
{=SUM(IF(B2<B$1:B1,1,0))<>0}
```

Please note, this is an array formula, so you need to hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER when you enter the formula for it to work.

It gives me this:

[image: Result]

If you prefer `R1C1` mode, like I do, the formula is:

```
{=SUM(IF(RC[-1]<R1C[-1]:R[-1]C[-1],1,0))<>0}
```